# SAS - Automate Change in Data Source to Provide Report

Tags: sql, sas, sas-macro, proc-sql

I currently have a program that Generates a full report (Data Manipulation, Analysis, Formatting, Excel output)  based on a few internal parameters.

I would like to build a tool or Macro that will iterate through 6 data sets, and provide a report for each of these Data sets independently.

In a process flow manner:

Input Data -> Program Operates -> Report Generation Output

I need to be able to change that Input Data Set on the fly.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated:

FYI - I've tried making a Prompt, but the "Data Source" Option does not allow me to choose a new Data Source.

Comment: Have you tried writing a macro for this? If so, can you please share what you have tried so far

Comment: I have made attempts to modify,  this tutorial: http://goo.gl/130rME

Comment: I have not used Dictionary Tables or Memname previously. my datasets are located in one directory, but alongside many other data files.

Comment: Your question is pretty generic right now. If you want something more specific, you need to make it more specific.

Comment: Data Source option? You may need to provide where and what that data source is. It may be easily fixed with a macro variable.

Comment: The Data Source option is legitimate, but the issue is having the data source change using a Macro, or some other procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The general structure to writing something like this is to make the data source name or connection details a macro parameter.  This assumes your other steps are all the same (or are all similarly parametrized). Something like

```
%macro run_reports(datasource=);

proc freq data=&datasource.;
run;

%mend run_reports;

%run_reports(datasource=mydata1);
%run_reports(datasource=mydata2);
```

Obviously there is more complexity inside than that, but that's the basic idea.  You may be able to programmatically generate the macro calls as well if there is a logical method of doing so.

Comment: Ok This is exactly the direction i would like to go.

Comment: In %macro run_reports(datasource=);  - Is the (datasource=) a path to the location of the data or are the data file names in a table that is  ordered.

Comment: That depends on your needs.  In my case it's a datasetname, but if you are using a .dat file or something instead you could have the filename/path.

Comment: Thanks Joe,  I think my main issue is that I do not know what structure the data sets need to be in. For example, If i have the data file in one file is that enough for the the macro to iterate through them. OR Do i need to have the names of each data file in an ordered chart.

Comment: You don't provide nearly enough information to answer that question.  You can do it almost any number of ways.  All data in one file with a classification variable and/or logic to distinguish; all data in separate datasets each named appropriately; data in many different places.  All can be worked with pretty easily.